# I have some problems with 'pom.xml' spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

**Like my title, I have some problems with my spring-boot project.**

My error message :

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.ta:TestAutomation:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE from http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/ was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Spring Plugins has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.4.RELEASE from/to Spring Plugins (http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): 
Access denied to http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom. 
Error code 403, Forbidden and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

And My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ta</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>TestAutomation</name>
    <description>Test-automation project by BAEK SEUNGJIN</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.7</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Spring Plugins</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- spring base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl, jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- mybatis - jdbc - oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz scheduler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I cannot understand... these errors occurred... just recent.

Last year, there were no any problems.

This project is running project in real server. I must do some updates, but cannot do because of this.

Anyone knows solution? Thank you.

Comment: Look like relative path issue .

Comment: you should put the parent pom.xml path in the `<relativePath>...</relativePath>` node if there is any. for example: `<relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>` . If there is no local pom, omit the node from your `pom.xml`

Comment: The simply issue is that maven repositories in the meantime only available via https instead of http for details https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https that is also valid for spring repos... apart from that spring boot etc. are also available within Maven Central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a firewall issue. The file is there and there's no reason for the Spring maven repos to deny you access to them unless maybe you've been blacklisted for some reason.

First check whether the machine you're trying to run the build on is connected to the internet, and whether there are firewalls blocking traffic to and from it.

Most likely that's your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is... I can connect "repo.spring.io/..." on my chrome browser. I think if there were firewall or internet connection problems, as you told, I may can't connect on my web browser.

Comment: I found problem! It was java version issue. I used oracle not free java version(241). I changed it too low version, so the problem removed.

Comment: @BAEKSEUNGJIN good to hear. Best move to OpenJDK, what with the license issues with Oracle versions.